# Prove that the group $Z_2$ x $Z_4$ is not isomorphic to $Q_8$, the quaternion group of order 8.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, quaternions

I have never heard of the quaternion group until today by google searching. It has the elements {1, i, j, k, -i, -j, -k, -1} and some special operations. I have a couple of these exercises using the quaternion group. A little help would be great.

Comment: Prove that $Q_8$ is non-abelian, while $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is abelian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the multiplication table of $Q_8$ is
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrrr}
  & 1 & i & j & k \\ \hline
1 & 1 & i & j & k \\
i & i & -1 & k & -j \\
j & j & -k & -1 & i \\
k & k & j & -i & -1
\end{array}
$$
This table immediately implies that $Q_8$ is not abelian and hence not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_4$.

Of course, we are utilizing the following lemma:

**Lemma.** Let $\phi:G\to H$ be a group isomorphism where $G$ is abelian. Then $H$ is abelian.

*Proof.* Let $h_1,h_2\in H$. Then there are $g_1,g_2\in G$ satisfying $\phi(g_i)=h_i$. It follows that 
$$
h_1h_2=\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)=\phi(g_1g_2)=\phi(g_2g_1)=\phi(g_2)\phi(g_1)=h_2h_1
$$
Hence $H$ is abelian. $\Box$

Comment: Very interesting, so for 2 groups to be isomorphic both of them have to be commutative or preserve certain properties in both sides?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: reading the definition, found the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Another argument is that there are 2 elements of order $2$ in  $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times  \mathbb{Z}_4$: $(0, 2)$ and $(1, 2)$, but there is only 1 element of order $2$ in $\mathbb{Q}_8$: $-1$.

Comment: Oh, nice. So the fact that one of them is abelian and the other one not, PLUS the fact that there are 2 elements of order 2 in $Z_2$ X $Z_4$ and just one of order 2 in $Q_8$. 

A little reminder on how to check order of elements? I'm in finals so any basic knowledge thrown at me would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either of these 2 arguments is sufficient. Order of an element $x$ is the minimum $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^n = e$.